# How do you play music in java?

Tags: java

I would like there to be several buttons in this GUI to play multiple sounds while at the same time editing a text file so the next time the program runs the songs playing upon closing are still playing. I've gotten to one song so far but it won't open and give me this error. I haven't been coding java for that long so I think its something stupid that I've missed.
[image]

The code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class AddSound extends JFrame {
    JButton Play = new JButton("Play");
    JButton Loop = new JButton("Loop");
    JButton Stop = new JButton("Stop");

    URL music1 = AddSound.class.getResource("music1.wav");
    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(music1);

    public AddSound() {
        super("AddingSound");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clip.play();
            }

        });

        Loop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clip.loop();
            }

        });

        Stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clip.stop();
            }

        });
        add(Play);
        add(Loop);
        add(Stop);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new AddSound();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(90, 90);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future post your exception message as text, not as an image, and indicate which line throws it. As it is, you're going to have to debug this one (after reading the close-link) as you are the only one with this information.

Comment: Also, where is the music1.wav file in relation to your class files? Are you looking in the right place for it?

Comment: I have put the file in the src file is that the right place?

Comment: try to print `music1` after the line where you initialize it.

Comment: But *where* in the source file?

Comment: `AddSound.class.getResource("music1.wav")` returned `null`. *Returns: A URL object or null if no resource with this name is found*

Comment: The src file is within the project folder labeled Audio Synthensizer located in the C drive within another folder called 1111 also sry it took so long to reply school just had a lock down

Comment: Hey I just found out the problem instead of it belonging in the src folder it belonged in the bin folder. The tutorial I was watching said to put it in the src so I think there was a little mistake in the video

Comment: If you're using Eclipse then if you drag and drop it into your package explorer, it will copy to the bin folder actually.

Comment: Oh thanks for that, I'm just used to manually putting stuff into the files through the explorer bc I used other Text Editors